# Modeling relative contribution of a variable

Tags: modeling, forecasting

I am overthinking this for sure, but I am stumped. I have a historical data set of projects with hours of contribution by various positions. There are six types of projects. How can I model the average contribution of each position for future forecasting purposes? Linear regression doesn't work because that models the independent contribution of each position. The end goal is to establish a formula that will allow me to say "when working on project type 1, if position A contributes 40 hours, then positions B and C usually need X hours a piece."

The data look like this:

```
Total Hours    Project Type    Position A    Position B    Position C
200                  1         100           40            60
140                  2         40            60            40
```

And so on for about 700 projects.

Comment: Is your problem to model the pct% of hours contributed by each position? You might want to try a logratio transform--see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data

Comment: What variables will you know when you do the forecasting?  Will you know the total hours? project type? contribution from position A?  i.e. what part of the above table will be blank when you do your forecast?

Comment: Most likely total hours will be known (or estimated, anyway). I'm reading up on compositional data analysis now.